# Solo Mining Difficulty?

Tags: p2pool

So I finally got P2Pool up and running after a lot of trial and error. When I launched my miner, I noticed that the Network Difficulty is the same as Bitcoins overall difficulty (1.93T). When I mined in pools they would always adjust to an appropriate level, such as 200 or even down to 1. Is this just how solo mining works or is there something that I can adjust, because I will never get a share at that high of a difficulty.

Comment: I figured it out! (Kind of) I had originally connected my miner via http://. When attempting to use port 9332 it always gave me an error, so I had used a random port which allowed me to connect. Finally I tried using stratum+tcp:// with the 9332 port and that is what fixed it. I cannot set the difficulty though, so I am fluctuating between 1 and 3. Any suggestions on how to bump that up?